# Is it very bad to create real time chat app in PHP 7?

Tags: performance, real-time, php-7, php-7.2

I'm creating PHP MySQL real time chat app. A friend told me It is very bad to use PHP for real time apps & that would kill server CPU.

I know that PHP isn't the proper choice but **i wanna get some advices to make the performance better with using PHP for real time chat apps**.

I also wanna know why some developers prefer using PHP7 over NodeJS/Socket.IO/GO/..etc ?

Thanks,,

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Nodejs + Socket for realtime chat application because of one reason that it will be completely Javascript from Browser/Mobile to server and if NoSql is database than upto database as well.

But your point of PHP7 vs Nodejs/Socket left me with a question and to get the answer I came across this blog. This might help you as well. Its too long to explain it here.

[PHP7 vs Nodejs](https://belitsoft.com/php-development-services/php7-vs-nodejs)

Comment: I upvoted your post +1 .. thnx for your help .. it wasn't me who downvoted your post ..

Comment: Thats ok actually. Thank you for your support. All we are here because we want to learn from our own mistakes. To correct it I wanted to know the reason. But, hope this answer has helped you.